# Connect an existing user account permanently to twitter to auto-tweet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter, twitter-oauth

I want to be able to connect an existing user account to his twitter account.

I want to give the option for the user to connect  his twitter account. After that is done once, I would like to be able to auto-tweet to his account.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try these 2 gems

> gem 'omniauth-twitter' and  gem "twitter" 
>   Register your App on twitter app site .Do the configuration accordingly. After setting the configuration in your controller you just have to do.

```
    @twitter = Twitter::Client.new(oauth_token: request.env["omniauth.auth"][:credentials][:token], oauth_token_secret: request.env["omniauth.auth"][:credentials][:secret])
    @twitter.update("Your message")
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully tweeted on your account."
    # redirect_to members_user_earns_path
    render "post"
```